# How to reload ConstraintLayout from java code

Tags: android, android-layout

We Need to reload this MyLayout class from myLayout class any Function

class MyLayout(context: Context) : ConstraintLayout(context) {

```
fun show() {
    val view = ImageView(context)
    addView(view)
    val params = view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
    params.height = 45
    params.width = 200
    params.rightToRight = id
    view.requestLayout()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To reload/redraw a view you should use

```
view.invalidate();
```

This will execute the onDraw method of view.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. But when we call MyLayout(this) then onDraw method not call.